# How to populate a Drop-down property control with a list of existing Filtering Schemes?

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer, spotfire-analyst

I am trying to investigate if it's possible to build logic into the *Web Player* so that is able to **Create** and **Change** Filtering Schemes using property controls in a *Text Area*. Currently, this functionality is limited to the Spotfire Analyst only.

At the moment, I am trying to figure out how to populate a **drop-down** property control as soon as the document is opened with the existing filtering schemes. Does anyone have any pointers on how to do that or if it's even possible?

This is what my end result will look like (after I get all the pieces to work together if it's even possible):

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, Spotfire hasn't added the ability to directly add/change dropdownlist chocies in ironpython.  Historically, I've done it by writing back to a table and refreshing the data set.  This link does something similar: https://community.tibco.com/questions/spotfire-add-new-values-dropdown-list-using-script

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look